# Add elements of second array to the end of first array

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I got an array of 2 elements with a structure:

```
typedef struct dataPar
    {
        unsigned long       indexGroup; 
        unsigned long       indexOffset;            
        unsigned long       length;         
    } TDataPar;
TDataPar parReq[2];

typedef struct dataPar2
    {
        unsigned long       data;   
    } TDataPar2;
TDataPar2 parReqData[2];
```

The data from the second array (`parReqData`) needs to be added at the end of array1(`parReq`)
it needs to be behind the first array
I will need to create a 3rd array where both data will be in
I thought something of:  `BYTE tempArray = new BYTE[sizeof(parReq)+sizeof(parReqData)`
and then copy both arrays into `tempArray`, just don't find out how

Answer (score 1):

```
BYTE* tempArray = new BYTE[sizeof(parReq)+sizeof(parReqData)]
memcpy(tempArray, parReq, sizeof(parReq));
memcpy(tempArray + sizeof(parReq), parReqData, sizeof(parReqData));
```

Answer (score 1):

thank you John, works perfectly!!

is it also possible if i do allmost the same, but instead of fixed array i use pointer arrays, so i can declare an array with a variable size:
i got 3 arrays

```
struct dataPar100
{
    unsigned long       indexGroup; 
    unsigned long       indexOffset;    
    unsigned long       length; 
};  
struct dataPar101
{
    unsigned long       data;   
};


unsigned short nrOfSymbols=3;
dataPar100 *parReq100 = new dataPar100[nrOfSymbols];
dataPar101 *parReq101 = new dataPar101[nrOfSymbols];
```

Answer (score 1):

sorry, found it

```
BYTE* tempArray2 = new BYTE[nrOfSymbols*(sizeof(*parReq100)+sizeof(*parReq101))];
        memcpy(tempArray2, parReq100, (nrOfSymbols*sizeof(*parReq100)));
        memcpy(tempArray2 + (nrOfSymbols*sizeof(*parReq100)), parReq101, (nrOfSymbols*sizeof(*parReq101)));
```